# Synchronous Ajax request will cause any issue on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made my ajax request in synchronous mode **not** in **asynchronous** mode. Will this below code is okay? Will this cause any issue on the page?

Or else, Give me some idea how to make ajax request to store values in a variable.

```
var myPage = myPage || {};

myPage.datas = (function(){
var myvar='';
$.ajax({
async: false,
    type:'GET',
    url: 'JSON/carousel-data.json',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       myvar = data;   
    }
});
return myvar;
})();
```

Comment: The page will be completely blocked during the ajax request.. so **bad idea**

Comment: How about using promises

Comment: Could anyone please provide good idea as well on this? I am really looking for good idea..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use *async:false*, as mentioned by Arun the browser will be blocked and there is no obvious reason to do synchronous calls in your above example. You may store values in the Window's scope i.e. `window.carouselData= data`, the created variable will remain until the browser is reloaded.

Comment: There is many examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

a better, non ui-freezing, approach is:

```
var myPage = myPage || {};
myPage.loadData = function(onDataLoaded){
    var me = this;
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'JSON/carousel-data.json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //set myPage.data
            myPage.data = data;
            onDataLoaded(data);
        }
    });
};
myPage.loadData(function(data){
    //do stuff with the data...
    //initialize your page or something
    // the data is set on myPage.data in the success callback
});
```

or you could use promises. It's basically the similar... here is a jQuery implementation:

```
var myPage = myPage || {};
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'JSON/carousel-data.json',
        dataType: "json"
    })
).done(function(result) {
    //the data is set on myPage.data
    myPage.data = result[0];

    //do stuff with the data...
    //initialize your page or something
});
```

Comment: This is not working as expected, It is not storing the values to the myPage.data? Any help?

Comment: My intention here anyway i need to store response data to namespace value.Any help?